# flutter widget placement at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm new to flutter and am attempting to create a generic sign on page. Right now I have the flutter logo and the google sign on form. I'm looking to create a "Have a Question" section at the bottom of the page. For now I'm just looking to have the text component at the bottom of the page.

I came across Expanded Widgets and this seem to fill what I needed, but in reality it didnt end up being what I wanted.

I also want to in the future add more authentication methods where the image would push up, but the text at the bottom remain the same

[image: What it currently looks like with Expanded Widget]

[image: What I want it to look like]

Current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gameface_mobile/sign_in.dart';

import 'first_screen.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlutterLogo(size: 150),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              _signInButton(),
              Expanded(
                child: _faq()
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithGoogle().then((result) {
          if (result != null) {
            print('Result: $result');
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        });
      },
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
      highlightElevation: 0,
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: AssetImage("assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in with Google',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _faq() {
    return Align(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () => {},
          child: Text("FAQ")
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply, you can take one more column with expanded, remove expanded for bottom widget –

Answer (score 3):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        _buildMainContent(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
            child: Text("FAQ"),
         ),
       ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Put the rest of your widget tree in `_buildMainContent()`, maybe you have to play around with the alignment a bit but that should basically be it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `stack` widget.

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          YourBody(),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: TheBottomWidget(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold also has an *bottom* property just like *body*, you can also pass an widget in it. It would help you to place any widget at bottom of screen .

Comment: The property is actually called bottomNavigationBar.